# Обратная Польская Запись

Tags: c++, польская-запись

Как я могу реализовать ОПЗ? Вот создал стек. Сам метод знаю. Но как рассмотреть элементы на знаки +, -, *, /? Чтобы отделить цифры от знаков?

Comment: Сравнивая их числовые кодировки.

Comment: вам в стек запихнуть или стек уже с числами-цифрами есть, нужно разобрать и посчитать?

Comment: Вместе с токеном хранить код его типа.

Answer (score 3):

Если задача заключается в преобразовании строки выражения из обычной записи, то знак соответственно, то что между цифрами. Можно для удобства воспользоваться двустековой реализацией, когда один стек хранит числа, а другой операции. Например если символ не число, а знак можно перечислить в условии. Нечто на вроде:

```
if(simbol=='+'||simbol=='-'||simbol=='*'||simbol=='/'){...}
```

Или наоборот отталкиваться от того, что символ не число:

```
if(simblol<'0'||simbol>'9') {...}
```

Если есть возможность, то лучше воспользоваться регулярными выражениями и из строки достать все знаки стоящие сразу после цифры и заменить на пробелы, а потом уже заполнить второй стек цифрами этой строки.