# вычисление выражения без вещ. типов данных

Tags: c

В стандартный поток ввода поступает выражение вида: `_._ _ _ _ + _ _ _._ _`, где «`_`» – цифра, а «`+`» - знак сложения. Числа, подаваемые на вход, записываются без пробелов. На вход подаются только числа, точки и знак "плюс", причем заведомо некорректный ввод невозможен. Для выполнения данного задания нельзя использовать вещественные типы данных. Лишние нули в дроби не выводить. Вывести ответ в стандартный поток вывода.

```
Пример ввода 1:
2.9900+001.92
Вывод:
4.91

Пример ввода 2:
9.3819+909.99
Вывод:
919.3719

Пример ввода 3:
0.0000+009.01
Вывод:
9.01

Пример ввода 4:
7.1999+902.90
Вывод:
910.0999
```

Мне нужно понять как производить эти вычисления,  подскажите или покажите  на примере как это сделать,  а остальное я сам

Comment: Как минимум неполная постановка задачи. В каком виде заданы эти числа? В каком диапазоне находятся значения слагаемых?..

Comment: Да в столбик...

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д

Comment: Вообще можно просто через int или short,но только дробь просто пропадет

Comment: вот я написал полное задание,  можете мне объяснить как выполнить эти вычисления?

Comment: Не надо заниматься вандализмом!

Comment: Во новичка кроет)

Comment: Такие вопросы касательно с++ уже на stackoverflow есть, и называется это чудо - обратная польская запись. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/153619/Обратная-Польская-Запись и вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23842/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9

Comment: Vasily, если Вы передумали задавать вопрос, Вы можете просто его удалить.

Comment: Я уже ришил все, через арифметику

Answer (score 1):

Как я бы решал эту задачу.

Вначале читаем строку, разбиваем по символу плюса. В принципе, если использовать scanf/sscanf, то это можно сделать в один приход.

```
char f[100];
char s[100];
sscanf(line, "%[^+]+%[^+]", f,s);
```

ок, теперь у нас есть две строки.

Дальше, проверяем, если там точки. Тут можно сделать оптимизации, но я думаю, можно пренебречь и если точки нет, то добавить ее в конец. strlen для длины строки и strchr для нахождения символа.

Сравниваем позицию точки и дополняем нулями число с меньшим кол-вом цифр после запятой.

Теперь, по старинке, справа налево складываем числа, учитываем перенос и не забываем пропустить точку. Цифры как символы легко складывать.

```
int n = (c1-'0' + c2 - '0');
```

Последний этап удаление нулей в десятичной части справа налево до точки. Если последний символ точка - также удаляем. Тут просто while от конца.

Comment: Супер! И не надо никаких мантисс и порядков. :-) Но ТС, видимо, на нас обиделся. Какую-то странную строку написал в вопросе. :-)

Comment: ТС все правильно написал.

Comment: Написал все правильно, а потом стер и написал странную строку. Поглядите в правках, там осталось. :-)

Comment: так я и поправил все, что бы было как нужно

Answer (score 0):

Можно в лоб, то есть по определению. Завести два целых поля - мантиссу и порядок. Нормировать порядки и складывать мантиссы. Это у Вас учебное задание что-ли?

UPD1:

Посмотрите определение чисел с плавающей запятой по  IEEE 754 как там их складывают и действуйте. Начать смотреть можно хотя бы с википедии:

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9

UPD2:

"Вещественные числа" это в математике. В программировании это называется "числа с плавающей запятой".